# Calculating tax using moneyphp

Tags: php, currency, tax, money-php

I am using the [moneyphp/money](https://github.com/moneyphp/money) class to store monetary values. However when calculating the tax owed I have an issue where the calculated tax is a decimal and the library is looking for an integerish value.

Example:

```
$invoiceTotal = new Money("155" new Currency("USD")); //$1.55
$taxRate= 0.065;
$invoiceTotalWithTax = $invoiceTotal->multiply($taxRate);
echo $invoiceTotalWithTax; //0.10 whereas actual value is 1.55*0.065 = 0.10075
$formatter = new DecimalMoneyFormatter();
$formatter->format($invoiceTotalWithTax); //will return $0.10
```

From the above example, some fractional cent value is being lost. Individually it's not a lot, however if we process several thousand invoice in a tax period, the total tax collected will eventually surpass 1 cent.

- Is there a way to handle these situations with the Money package?
- If not, then is there another package that can handle this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shameless plug: I don't know if there's a way to do it with the `moneyphp/money` library, but here's how you can handle this situation with the [brick/money](https://github.com/brick/money) library (disclaimer: I authored it).

The option you choose will depend on what you're trying to achieve.

#### Option 1: use a Money with the default scale, round up or down

Use this method if you need the result in the default scale for the currency (2 decimal places for `USD`), and know which rounding to apply:

```php
use Brick\Money\Money;
use Brick\Math\RoundingMode;

$invoiceTotal = Money::ofMinor('155', 'USD'); // USD 1.55
// or
$invoiceTotal = Money::of('1.55', 'USD');

$taxRate = '0.065'; // prefer strings over floats!

$totalWithTax = $invoiceTotal->multipliedBy($taxRate, RoundingMode::DOWN); // USD 0.10
$totalWithTax = $invoiceTotal->multipliedBy($taxRate, RoundingMode::UP); // USD 0.11
```

You have many more [rounding modes](https://github.com/brick/math/blob/0.7.3/src/RoundingMode.php) to choose from. If you don't provide a rounding mode, and the result does not fit into 2 decimal places, you'll get an exception.

#### Option 2: use a Money with a custom scale

If you need to work with a given precision, say 5 decimal places, you can specify this when you create the Money:

```php
use Brick\Money\Money;
use Brick\Money\Context\CustomContext;
use Brick\Math\RoundingMode;

$invoiceTotal = Money::of('1.55', 'USD', new CustomContext(5)); // USD 1.55000
$taxRate = '0.065';

$totalWithTax = $invoiceTotal->multipliedBy($taxRate); // USD 0.10075
```

If the result does not fit into 5 decimal places, you'll need to provide a `RoundingMode`, or you'll get an exception.

#### Option 3: use a Money with auto scale

Use this method to automatically adjust the scale of the result to the correct number of decimal places:

```php
use Brick\Money\Money;
use Brick\Money\Context\AutoContext;
use Brick\Math\RoundingMode;

$invoiceTotal = Money::of('1.55', 'USD', new AutoContext()); // USD 1.55
$taxRate = '0.065';

$totalWithTax = $invoiceTotal->multipliedBy($taxRate); // USD 0.10075
```

No rounding mode is involved, but if a division yields a decimal number with an infinite number of digits, you'll get an exception.

#### Option 4: use a RationalMoney

A `RationalMoney` is a money object that represents its amount as a rational number (a fraction). It's particularly useful when you need to chain several operations **with no rounding** whatsoever:

```php
use Brick\Money\Money;
use Brick\Math\RoundingMode;

$amount = Money::of('1.55', 'USD'); // USD 1.55
$amount = $amount->toRational(); // USD 155/100

$amount = $amount->dividedBy(3); // USD 155/300
$amount = $amount->dividedBy(7); // USD 155/2100
```

Once you have performed all your operations, you can convert your final number to a decimal Money, using a rounding mode if necessary:

```php
use Brick\Money\Context\DefaultContext;
use Brick\Money\Context\CustomContext;

$amount->to(new DefaultContext(), RoundingMode::DOWN); // USD 0.07
$amount->to(new CustomContext(6), RoundingMode::DOWN); // USD 0.073809
```

#### Final considerations

The [brick/money](https://github.com/brick/money) package offers formatting, cash roundings, money allocation, currency conversion, and more. It is based on the [brick/math](https://github.com/brick/math) package, that performs calculations on numbers of any scale. Give it a try!

Comment: Nice library! How do you make comparisons? Like to check if an amount is greater|lower|equal than another? Can't find documentation on it

Comment: @ElGucs Check `isGreaterThan()` etc., these methods are in `AbstractMoney`!

Comment: Asked and got that info, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Other possibility without worrying about roundings etc would be this:

```
use Money\Money;
$grossTotalMoney = Money::EUR(12345); // 123.45 €
list($net_total, $tax_total) = $grossTotalMoney->allocate([100 - $tax_percentage, $tax_percentage]);
```

https://www.moneyphp.org/en/stable/features/allocation.html

Answer (score 0):

The current solution is actually much simpler than any of the above, just wrap your decimal/float in quotes to cast it as a `string` when supplying to the `Money` object, it will convert it back as necessary but maintain the fixed precision that `float` does NOT offer. The `money\money` library is very explicit about not using float anywhere in the library.

```
$value = Money::CAD(1000);         // $10.00
$tax = $value->multiply("0.13");  // 130 or $1.30, notice the quotes around the float.
```